# Connect input:file to input:text and input:button to select file

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I am using template for a system. However, I cant figure out how to connect the input:file to input:text and input:button. It seems like the input:file is hidden in this template and I have to use the input:text(It is disabled) and input:button. Here's the code:

```
<div class="form-group">
     <label>File upload</label>
     <input type="file" name="img[]" class="file-upload-default">
     <div class="input-group col-xs-12">
          <input type="text" class="form-control file-upload-info" disabled="" placeholder="Upload Image">
          <span class="input-group-append">
               <button class="file-upload-browse btn btn-info" type="button">Upload</button>
          </span>
     </div>
</div>
```

I have to use it on multer. How can I pass up the data too? Even multiple uploads. Sorry. Thanksss.

Comment: Why is the file input control hidden?

Comment: I dont know either. It's from a bootstrap template. I think there is some things I need to do to connect the input:text and input:button to the input:file.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```html
<html lang="en">
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<head>
<body>
<div class="form-group form-file" >
     <label>File upload</label>
     <input type="file" name="img[]" class="file-upload-default" id="file-1" style="display:none" onchange="checkFile(this)">
     <div class="input-group col-xs-12">
          <input type="text" class="form-control file-upload-info" disabled="" placeholder="Upload Image">
          <span class="input-group-append">
               <button class="file-upload-browse btn btn-info" type="button" onclick="$('#file-1').click()">Upload</button>
          </span>
     </div>
</div>


</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var count_file=1;

    function checkFile(dom){
        if($(dom)[0].files[0]){
            console.log($(dom).parent().find('.file-upload-info'));
            var d=$(dom).parent().find('.file-upload-info')[0];
                d.value=($(dom)[0].files[0].name);
        }

    }



</script>
    


</script>
```